# Create PDF from HTML using AWS Lambda and consuming imgs from a S3 Bucket with Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, xhtml2pdf

I have this issue in which I hope that someone can help me with.
So I have a process that saves some images into a S3 bucket.

Then, I have a lambda process, that using python, it's supposed to create a PDF file, displaying these images.

I'm using the library xhtml2pdf for that, which I've uploaded to my lambda environment as a layer.

My 1st approach was to download the image from the S3 bucket, and save it into the lambda '/tmp', but I was getting this error from xhtml2pdf:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/python/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf_reportlab.py", line 359, in __init__
raise RuntimeError('Imaging Library not available, unable to import bitmaps only jpegs')
RuntimeError: Imaging Library not available, unable to import bitmaps only jpegs fileName= 
<_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f1eaabe49a0>
```

Then I thought that if I had it being transformed into a base64 file, that this issue would be solved, but then I got the same error.

Can anybody here, please, give me some guidance about the best way to do this ?

Thank you

This is a small piece of my lambda code:

```
from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def getFileFromS3(fileKey, fileName):
    try:
        localFileName = f'/tmp/{fileName}'
        
        bot_utils.log(f'fileKey : {fileKey}')
        bot_utils.log(f'fileName : {fileName}')
        bot_utils.log(f'localFileName : {localFileName}')

        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        bucketName = 'fileholder'
        
        s3.download_file(bucketName, fileKey, localFileName)
        
        return 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + getImgBase64( localFileName )
        
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        raise

htmlText = '<table>'
for i in range(0, len(shoppingLines), 2):
   product = shoppingLines[i]
   text = product['text']
   folderName = product['folder']

   tmpFile = getFileFromS3(f"pannings/{folderName}/{product['photo_id']}.jpg", f"{product['photo_id']}.jpg")
   htmlText += f"""<tr><td align="center"><img src="{tmpFile}" width="40" height="55"></td><td>{text}</td></tr>"""

htmlText += '</table>'

result_file = open('/tmp/file.pdf', "w+b")
pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(htmlText ,dest=result_file)
result_file.close()
```

Comment: Which line exactly is producing the error? Also what exactly is the type of the image? Any examples?

Comment: The line that creates the pdf
`pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(htmlText ,dest=result_file)`

And the imagem is a simple jpg... nothing fancy

Comment: From my investigations, seems like a issue with PIL... 
I've included PIL into the zip file that I use as layer for xhtml2pdf... but I'm not sure... 
maybe I should user a different library... or use a node.js lambda only for that...

Answer (score 0):

For future google searches.
Seems like the issue is with the PIL/Pillow library.
I've found a version of these library on this GIT repo (https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers)
When I use this version, it works...